# visual studio 2015 locks user temp folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, environment-variables, windows-10

I am using windows 10 pro, and visual studio 2015.

I found my third party dll cannot access my user temp folder(%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp) that is defined in the environment variables.

I created c:\UserTemp folder, changed the user environment variable pointing to that that folder.

After I run VS, I found VS created some folders under the c:\UserTemp folder. Then the third party cannot create a file there. I close VS, deleted the VS created folders. Then I run my application outside VS, this time the third party was able to create a file there now. Also with VS created folders under c:\UserTemp folder, if I tried to edit the folder permission for uses, it displayed an error.

Is there anyway I can do let VS do not lock the user temp folder? If the folder being locked, I cannot run my application inside VS and debug it.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the error when you try to change the permissions for the folder? Did you try to run VS as Admin?

Comment: The error is "An error occurred while applying security information to:
C:\Us...\Report.96...
Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied. "